# cannot open source file "iostream" и др. VS code

Tags: c++, header, visual-studio-code

Программа работает. `cout` выводит текст. Путь к директории с `include` указан, но пишет `cannot open source file "iostream"`

Код Json

```
name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceRoot}",
                "C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gсс/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"

            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceRoot}",
                    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/gсс/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/include/c++"
                ],
```

Comment: А что это у вас `"intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64"` а компилятор mingw, да еще видимо от dev-cpp? Раз уж вы на windows, то поставьте себе полноценную студию.

Comment: ...Или хотя бы новенький MinGW-w64.